# Should the controllers be aware of NSManagedObjectContext in an iOS application

Tags: objective-c, ios, model-view-controller, user-interface, core-data

In an iOS application that I am refactoring, I am using Core Data as the main persistence layer. I  am trying to refactor towards a proper MVC pattern. However, I have been trying to remove NSManagedObject* objects from the UI, because I believe the models should be what care about the persistence layer.

I am struggling to decide one way or another if I should allow the UI to retain an NSManagedObjectContext, or if the models should maintain a context for retrieving the information requested by the UI, then return a dumb object (not an NSManagedObject) to the the UI. With my experience, I am inclined to want to have the models know of all persistence to separate concerns, but I also struggle to justify that pattern.

Can someone help me to make sense of what I should do and why?

Comment: What do you mean by UI in this case?  A common pattern is to pass an NSManagedObjectContext to a UIViewController.  From there you can set properties on your view using the NSManagedObjects themselves.  The controller (UIViewController) is managing the bridge between the model layer and the view (the UIViewController's view).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much thought, reading, and other review, I have decided that it is acceptable for controllers to be aware of the context. The context can be used more or less as a model, and as long as the view logic is not aware of it, then it doesn't violate MVC.

I personally would rather keep contexts under a service layer, and I do try to keep them underground, but having a UI managed object context comes with a great amount of convenience; just make sure you understand the cost.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, The `NSPersistanceStoreCoordinator` is a stack of `NSManagedObjectContexts` as a graph of `NSManagedObjects`. You can and should use multiple Managed Object Contexts to perform tasks in the UI seperate from background calculations. This will prevent a deadlock due to different threads sharing the same `NSManagedObjectContext`.

When saving information to two seperate NSManagedObjectContext's you need to merge the changes to the other threads context using.

```
- (void)mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
```

Summarized from parts of the Core Data Programming Guide.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/CoreData.pdf

Comment: Did this answer your questions?

Comment: No it did not. I understand how to use multiple contexts in threads and to divide work, but I have a strong issue with domain knowledge being in the controller level. Putting a context up into the UI abstraction seems like a very bad pattern.